# Windows Server 2003 sp2 kills ASP.NET 1.1 web apps

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2003

We recently upgraded our intranet dev server (Windows Server 2003) to the latest and greatest patches, including 2k3 sp2 and the latest for each version of .NET.

We have a variety of technologies that we use, including COM+, ASP, ASP.NET 1.1, ASP.NET 2.0, and ColdFusion. So testing can be, well, interesting, as those technologies don't always play nice together.

We've already applied a hot fix to address a COM+ issue. The current problem revolves around the fact that ASP.NET 1.1 web applications simply don't work any more. Any aspx page simply throws a generic "page not found" error; static files (e.g. .html) return as normal. Identical code still works properly in our unpatched test environment.

The virtual folders are setup to run in their own application pool (separate from ASP.NET 2.0). The only google-found tip I found was to change the .NET to 2.0 for the virtual folder. It did seem to work, but I worry that it will hose the server (since that's what happened in the past when someone accidentally didn't configure an app's .NET pool correctly).

While our plan is to finish upgrading our existing applications to 2.0, it won't happen in the near term. Is there a hot fix that eluded my search? Or perhaps another work around that someone has implemented?

**Additional information:**

Both servers in question are 32 bit.
Here's a snippet from the IIS log for the 404 error:

2008-11-25 23:58:41 10.150.1.31 GET /revenue/MailerAdmin.aspx - 80 - 10.1.3.18 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+MPI+INTERNAL;+InfoPath.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322; +.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+MS-RTC+LM+8;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648; +MPI+INTERNAL;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+MPI+INTERNAL) 404 2 1260

Comment: 1. Can you show the iis log of the 404 errors?
2. Are the servers 32 bit?

Comment: Yes, the servers are 32 bit. I've updated the post with a sample log entry (too large for comment section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0f4ac79a-dc2b-4a5f-89c1-d57266aa6ffe.mspx?mfr=true) for the 404 2 1260 error. Look at the "Web service extention" folder under the IIS manager. verify that the ASP.NET v1.1.4322 is registered and allowed. If not. use the aspnet_regiis.exe tool from the .net directory.